# How to omit parts of a line while reading a text file in MATLAB (2016 and above)

Tags: matlab, io, text-parsing

I need to develop a MATLAB code to read a text file.
The lines have the following form:

```
|     1 |   1   |      6.000 |    454.000 |      423 |

|     1 |   1   |     11.000 |   -454.000 |      426 |

|     1 |   1   |     45.000 |    454.000 |      428 |
```

Is there a way to omit the vertical bars (and just keep the numbers?)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB offers [multiple different file IO options](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/text-files.html)

For example, you could use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html):

```
fID = fopen('test.txt');
test = textscan(fID, '%*u %u %u %f %f %u', 'Delimiter', '|');
fclose(fID);
```

Which returns an `n x 5` [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of your columns that you can manipulate/concatenate as desired.

Or you could use [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html):

```
mydata = readtable('test.txt', 'Delimiter', '|', 'Format', '%*u %u %u %f %f %u');
```

Which returns an `n x 5` [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html) of your data.